# Footer not coming in proper place

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

When I don't have the content on my page the footer goes up. My code in layout file is this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
     <!--<div class="span3">
      <div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
            <li><%#= link_to "Link1", "/path1"  %></li>
            <li><%#= link_to "Link2", "/path2"  %></li>
            <li><%#= link_to "Link3", "/path3"  %></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!/.well -->
    <!-- </div> -->
    <div class="span9">
      <div id="alert">
          <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
         <%= content_tag :div, :id=>'flash_msg', :class => "alert alert-#{key}" do %>
         <%= value unless value.blank? %>                         
         <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
         <% flash.discard -%> 
       <% end %>
      <% end %>   
      </div>   
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div><!--/row-->
<footer class="footer-fix">
    <p>&copy; <%= Time.now.strftime("%Y") -%> Icicle Technologies Private Limited </p>
</footer>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

When I put the footer outside the container-fluid class then also I get the same issue. What can I include in the css. Can someone help me?
For footer-fix the css is:

```
.footer-fix{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use** 
**[min-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)** property `which sets the minimum height of an element`..

```
.content-holder //whatever your div is
{
 min-height:500px;
}
```

**JsFiddle:** 
**http://jsfiddle.net/Cg9YZ/**

Hope this helps.

Comment: When there is more content in the page then the footer is not coming at the right place.

Comment: Can you show a link where the problem is or can you set up a fiddle??

Comment: I tried your option but when the the content is more then the blank space is inserted in the page. For small content it is working properly.

Comment: I have used the same css that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a footer as an absolute position which are not affected on any cases. You should write a css code as:

```
 .footer-fix
 {
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      bottom:0px;
      text-align:center;
      ...
 }
```

Comment: I tried this but the footer is not moving down if the content is more.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is something called as sticky footer. When you google this the first link yu get is to ryanfait.com. he has given the css for the same issue.

This is how the structure goes:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">Your contents other than footer content go here</div>
<div class="footer">footer content go here</div>
</body>
```

this will fix your issue:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's     height */
}
.footer, .push {
height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Comment: I had read those sticky notes. But I am not getting which class to use where i.e., wrapper and all other classes